# See installed userscripts on chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, userscripts

How can I see and manage the userscripts that I have installed on chrome?

I have tried looking for an option in the extensions section, but there is none.
is there a place/page that I can access that will give me the ability to update and remove the userscripts that I have installed chrome?

Comment: Userscripts should appear exactly like extensions in the Chrome settings.

Comment: @Josefvz, what version of Chrome are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage userscripts just like any other extension, from the `chrome://extensions` page.
You could also access it from the *Tools* menu under the wrench.

> [image: Wrench > Tools > Extensions]

Once on the extensions page, it should appear in the list just like any other extension. Take for example the [AutoReviewComments](https://stackapps.com/q/2116) userscript, it appears in the list just like any other extension.

> [image: AutoReviewComments Userscript]

Comment: I would have used the [YousableTubeFix](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/57201) script for the example `:-)`, but yes, they *should* be in the extensions page.

Comment: I was running an old version of chrome, once I updated I saw them.

Answer (score 1):

Like Bryan said, you *should* be able to see an manage [User Scripts](http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts/) in the extensions page (`chrome://extensions`). If for some reason you do not see them there, (and do not want to bother trying to figure out *why*), you can see the actual, installed files in the `Extensions` subdirectory of [your Chrome User Profile](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory):

```
%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

It’s not convenient and you could mess up your extensions if you are not careful, but if you really cannot see them in the extensions page, then accessing them at the file-level may be your only option.